# Using ROC curve to find optimum cutoff for my weighted binary logistic regression (glm) in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, roc, proc-r-package

I have build a binary logistic regression for churn prediction in Rstudio. Due to the unbalanced data used for this model, I also included weights. Then I tried to find the optimum cutoff by try and error, however To complete my research I have to incorporate ROC curves to find the optimum cutoff. Below I provided the script I used to build the model (fit2). The weight is stored in 'W'. This states that the costs of wrongly identifying a churner is 14 times as large as the costs of wrongly identifying a non-churner.

```
#CH1 logistic regression

library(caret)
W = 14
lvl = levels(trainingset$CH1)
print(lvl)
#if positive we give it the defined weight, otherwise set it to 1
fit_wts = ifelse(trainingset$CH1==lvl[2],W,1)
fit2 = glm(CH1 ~ RET + ORD + LVB + REVA + OPEN + REV2KF + CAL + PSIZEF + COM_P_C + PEN + SHOP, data = trainingset, weight=fit_wts, family=binomial(link='logit'))
# we test it on the test set
predlog1 = ifelse(predict(fit2,testset,type="response")>0.5,lvl[2],lvl[1])
predlog1 = factor(predlog1,levels=lvl)
predlog1
confusionMatrix(pred,testset$CH1,positive=lvl[2])
```

For this research I have also build ROC curves for decision trees using the pROC package. However, of course the same script does not work the same for a logistic regression. I have created a ROC curve for the logistic regression using the script below.

```
prob=predict(fit2, testset, type=c("response"))
testset$prob=prob
library(pROC)
g <- roc(CH1 ~ prob, data = testset, )
g
plot(g)
```

Which resulted in the ROC curve below.

[image]

How do I get the optimum cut off from this ROC curve?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work exactly? What error message are you seeing?

Comment: @Calimo I changed the text a little bit, hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: Do you have a definition of what you call "optimum"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the "optimal" cutoff is totally independent of the type of model, so you can get it like you would for any other type of model with pROC. With the `coords` function:

```
 coords(g, "best", transpose = FALSE)
```

Or directly on a plot:

```
plot(g, print.thres=TRUE)
```

Now the above simply maximizes the sum of sensitivity and specificity. This is often too simplistic and you probably need a clear definition of "optimal" that is adapted to your use case. That's mostly beyond the scope of this question, but as a starting point you should a look at [Best Thresholds section of the documentation of the coords function](http://search.r-project.org/library/pROC/html/coords.html) for some basic options.